# Feasible Multinomial Logit with large number of fixed effects

Tags: multinomial-distribution, logit, fixed-effects-model, clogit

Is there a way to run something similar to a multinomial logit model with a large number of fixed effects that converges in a reasonable amount of time (I am using Stata)?

Comment: Is this just a question about how to use Stata?

Comment: Nope, I can code it up to run, but its too slow. I was just wondering if there is another quicker way to estimate the model.

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?